# Updating entity with onetomany connection without ids in children entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following structure: tables "parents" and "children", which are binded by parents.id = children.parent_id

Application reads data from these tables into the object of the following class:

```
public class Parent {
    private int id;
    private Map<String, String> children;
    ....
}
```

Then application changes data in it.
What I need to do is to apply changes to existing records. I am not allowed to change Parent class or database structure. And I am trying to do this by using jpa repository by the following way:

My entities

```
@Repository
public interface ParentsDao extends JpaRepository<ParentEntity, Integer> {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
public class ParentEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Set<ChildEntity> children;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "children")
public class ChildEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", updatable = false)
    private ScheduledReportsEntity scheduledReport;

    @Column(name = "child_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "child_value")
    private String value;
    ...
}
```

The following is my sevice, where action() starts the whole thing: converts Parent to ParentEntity and saves it

```
public class ParentServiceImpl {
        @Autowired
        ParentsDao parentsDao;

        public 

void action(Parent parent) {
            ParentEntity entity = convert(parent);  // moving data from Parent to ParentEntity object
            parentsDao.save(entity); //here I receive exception
        }
        private ParentEntity convert(Parent parent) {

        Set<ChildEntity> children = new HashSet<ChildEntity>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : simpleObj.getChildren().entrySet()){
            ChildEntity childEntity = new ChildEntity();
            childEntity.setName(entry.getKey());
            childEntity.setValue(entry.getValue());
            children.add(entity);
        }

        ParentEntity entity = new ParentEntity();
        entity.setId(parent.getId());
        entity.setChildren(children);

        return entity;
    }
}
```

But I am receiving the following error:

```
com.app.impl.ParentServiceImpl: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: 
could not insert: [com.app.entities.ChildEntity]; 
SQL [insert into scheduled_report_params (child_name, child_value, parent_id) values (?, ?, ?)]; 
constraint [null]; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.app.entities.ChildEntity]
```

I have 2 questions:
1. I think this is connected to missing ids in children, am I right?
2. If the reason is missing ids, then are there any way to get around it somehow and provide save by other fields?
Will be greatfull for any advice.
Thanks

Comment: what does "without children containing their ids" mean? If there is a ChildEntity then it has an id and that is the way to identify it. No idea what the top example with Map is in relation to the code below

Comment: Application works with simple Parent, which contains map. In order to update, I convert it to ParentEntity by filling all fields. Map is converted to list of ChildEntities, but without ids, cause Parent simply doesn't have them. I guess your response means that there is no way to update child entities by other field then id. Am I right?

Comment: No idea what is "update". Map has a String key and String value (in a separate table). You do updates to the Map just as you would any Map and the JPA provider should update the table of the map. My JPA provider works fine. You only make something an Entity when it needs its own table.

Comment: I need the children map to be in a separate table. Yes, it creates ok new records, but fails to update existing records. So I thought it might be because of missing ids in children. Not sure if this will clarify something, but I updated the post. If missing ids is not the reason, then maybe you can advice where should I look. Thanks for responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a design problem.

You are right, if `id` is the primary key for child entity, it must be present in all pre-existent (not new) `ChildEntity` elements from the children Set of a `ParentEntity` element if you modify it. If not, Hibernate will try to insert them.

So you must choose between two solutions :

- use a generated primary key in `ChildEntity` and find a way to keep it in your application. For example, you could use `ParentEntity` as the *real* model class with `Parent` being a *view* on it :

  ```
  class Parent {
      private ParentEntity inner;
      public Parent(ParentEntity entity) {
          inner = entity;
          // initialize children or have getChildren to dynamically create it
          // from inner.childre
          ...
      }
  ...
  }
  ```
- use child name as the primay key. The `ChildEntity` would look like :

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "children")
  public class ChildEntity {
      @Id
      @Column(name = "child_name")
      private String name;

      @Column(name = "child_value")
      private String value;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", updatable = false)
      private ScheduledReportsEntity scheduledReport;
      ...
  }
  ```

But you cannot simply forget a primary key in your application.

Comment: Another one question - It looks like the only way for me is to make composite primary key of parent_id and child_name. The question is, is it possible to use parent_id both as a part of primary key and as a binder for manyToOne connection? Maybe you can advice usefull links with examples.. Thanks

Comment: I thing it is possible. You should look at Hibernate manual, Basic O/R mapping / Identifiers - I saw an example for *id as a property using a component type* that could be near to what you need.